# How to substitute values of multiple variables into an expression

Tags: rule

Brand new user here.
How to substitute values of multiple variables into an expression?

I try:

```
n + m /. {n, m} -> {2, 4}
# produces `m+n` as output
# or alternatively 
n + m /. n->2, m->4
# gives blank output
```

`n+5 ./ n->2` works and produces 7 as output.

Is `./` only for single variable substitutions?

Comment: `n + m /. Thread[{n, m} :>  {2, 4}]` would be one way

Comment: `n + m /. {n->2, m->4}`. Useful to understand difference between Replace and ReplaceAll (\.) for future work.

Comment: Here's some advice that helped me a lot when I was a new user: use the documentation!  It's not that bad! There is a convenient way to access it: highlight the function in question (in this case, highlight the `/.`) and hit F1 to access the documentation on that function (which is `ReplaceAll`). Two of the examples under `Basic Examples` show you exactly what you need.